# How to format 2021-12-17T06:23:49.000000Z?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to format this date `2021-12-17T06:23:49.000000Z` to read as `Dec 17,2021`. How do I achieve that?

This is what I have tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS.'Z'");
Date newDate= null;
try {
    newDate = spf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
spf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
date = spf.format(newDate);
```

Comment: How can `.SSSSSS.'Z'` *parse* `.000000Z`? the pattern has an extra dot between milliseconds and `Z`

Answer (score 7):

The biggest mistake you have here is using the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They are legacy, and have been retained mainly for backwards compatibility. The [`java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) package provides a far more consistent API. Like,

```
String date = "2021-12-17T06:23:49.000000Z";
OffsetDateTime inst = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(date), 
        ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").format(inst));
```

Outputs

```
Dec 17, 2021
```

Comment: Or automatically localize: `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.getDefault() )`